# Reading a json file - spring MVC

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring MVC ,I want to read a `json` file available in class path.

I want to know wheather we can give the json file in webconfig.java with `@PropertySource` annotation like property file and call it as `environment.getProperty` or please suggest a better way to read `json` file. I am using `wenconfig java` file instead of `xml`.

Comment: To make it clear, you are looking from using a JSON file as a sort of properties file? That won't work out of the box and I am not aware of any such implementation

Comment: @Neelu Neelu have a look [here](http://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-processing-api-in-java-example-tutorial) and [this](http://crunchify.com/java-properties-file-how-to-read-config-properties-values-in-java/)

Comment: You should however check out Spring Boot that has the ability to read YAML files. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-yaml